# The purpose of passing the web driver object into page object base class's constructor

Tags: java, selenium, oop, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have seen the web driver object is having in the page object base class level's constructor as follows.

Example:

```
public class PageObjectBase 
{
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public PageObjectBase(WebDriver driver){

        driver = this.driver;
    }
}

public class LoginPage extends PageObjectBase 
{

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){

        super(driver);
    }
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this approach? Why are we always passing driver object to base constructor?

Comment: I think this line is not doing what you think it's doing: `driver = this.driver;`

Comment: here's a quick example that should help illustrate what's wrong with `driver = this.driver;` – `public class Example { public static void main(String[] args) { X x = new X("foofy"); x.print(); } } class X { private String s; public X(String s) { s = this.s; } public void print() { System.out.println(s); } }` (this would be better to post as an Answer so it could have better formatting, but it isn't actually answering your question).

Comment: it might look like the above example should print out "`foofy`" but instead it prints `null`

Answer (score 3):

By initializing WebDriver in a base class, you can use this base class to keep track of your driver for easy setup and teardown, in a way that is isolated from the rest of your code.

Elaborating on your code a bit:

```
public class Base 
{
    public WebDriver driver;

    public Base(WebDriver driver){

        driver = this.driver;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public WebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        // perform steps to initialize WebDriver
        driver = this.driver
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void DestroyDriver()
    {
        driver.Close();
        driverQuit();
    }
}
```

Now, you can write test classes that inherit from `Base`. This gives you an instance of WebDriver to use in your code, and you don't have to perform Setup or Teardown in your test class either:

```
public class MyTestClass : Base
{
    // this test method will perform setup (inherited from base), run the test, then teardown (also inherited from base)
    public void MyTest_1()
    {
        // perform webdriver actions in the test case
        element = driver.FindElement(someSelector);

        // initialize a PageObject
        PageObject myPageObject = new PageObject(driver);

        // perform some action using a PageObject
        myPageObject.EnterTextIntoForm();
    }
}
```

You can also use this `driver` instance to initialize PageObjects:

```
public class MyPageObject
{
    public MyPageObject(driver)
    { }

    public void EnterTextIntoField
    {
       // we can use the same driver instance here
        driver.FindElement(someSelector).SendKeys(someField);
    }
}
```

So this pattern allows your WebDriver instance to be used in test cases and page objects to perform all sorts of testing functions. You can abstract setup and teardown into the base class, and you will not have to write the same setup and teardown method over and over in your code.

The only downside to this approach is that it takes longer to write a framework and adds a layer of complexity to your code. But there is really no down side, and abstracting your WebDriver into a base class as such is usually considered best practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanation.  Actually, this base class means pageobjectbase class. I could not mention it in the question and sorry for that. Please explain this approach also.

Comment: when you have a base page object as such, you can write methods and selectors that all of your page objects will need to use. Many websites re-use HTML components such as buttons. So instead of writing a selector for a similar button on every single page object, you can just write it once on the base page object and all of your other pages will inherit the base class, and access the shared selectors.